# Upgrade Visual Studio 2010 StartPage to 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, start-page

As I found no Information about my concern on google, I will try it here.

On Visual Studio 2010 it was possible to create [Custom Start Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee663382.aspx).
I did one by my own a year ago and I'm used to it now.

Well, as Visual Studio 2012 released, I wasn't able to use my (VSIX) Custom Start Page anymore.

On MSDN I found this: [How to: Upgrade Visual Studio SDK/VSIX Projects to Visual Studio 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567449.aspx), but after I made everything it still didn't work.

The Problem actually is, that there is NO "Start Page Project Template" (To find in Extension Manager) as in Visual Studio 2010.

So I found this: [How to: Manually Create a Start Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff425532.aspx), but its completly false and copy/paste as it leads to Visual Studio 2010 though it tells Visual Studio 2012 at the top.

After the Tutorial I got this:

```
<Grid    xmlns:sp="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI;assembly=Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.StartPage"
         xmlns:vs="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI;assembly=Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.11.0"
         xmlns:vsfx="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.11.0"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <Label Content="My ListView:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="White"/>
    <ListView Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Margin="10,40,10,10" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

That doesn't work in VS2012, but in VS2010 it works like a charm.

Well at least I had no choice, than to try things out by my own.
I used the tutorial in the last link I provided ([How to: Manually Create a Start Page)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff425532.aspx).

Beginning: **Creating a Blank Start Page** and on Step 5: *In the editor, change the top-level UserControl element to a Grid element without removing any of the namespace declarations.*

I didn't do that - I let it be a UserControl and I was able then to choose the XAML from the Tools>Options>StartPage>Customize Start Page , well the only problem is now, that I cant have CodeBehind, cause I had to remove the x:Class (Take a Look at Step 6)..

And inlinecode in the XAML is not an option, so please if someone can help me; how exactly I upgrade my VSIX Custom Start Page to VS2012 or how I create a working Blank StartPage with Codebehind ability or if I need to wait until someone releases the Start Page Project Template for VS2012, I would really appreciate it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least I wasn't able to solve my problem.. I created then everything from scratch and with InlineCode (for sure with XAML and WPF)

Answer (score 0):

This xaml file with Grid inside you should really treat like a 'shell' for your actual implementation. Move contents of your grid to a separate user control defined in a separate assembly (you can use code behind there). Then add xmlns reference and this new control to the Grid.

Xaml with grid goes to \Documents\Visual Studio 2010\StartPages\
Assembly with your user control goes to \Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies

Comment: at least I was able to finish my StartPage, I used XAML-Only without Codebehind, All Code has been written to a separate library/dll and I'm referencing it in the xaml..

Answer (score 0):

There's an article posted on MSDN now for upgrading VS2010 start pages to VS2012: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj991932.aspx